# web service request is returning null

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I am attempting to call a web service that is hosted on a java server.  I have created the classes through the web service creation tool provided with Visual Studio.  When I call the method, I can see in Fiddler that it is returning valid data.  However, in my C# code, my result is null.

Any help would be appreciated.

C# calling code:

```
RuleValidationResponseRule[] ruleResponse = rulesWebService.RuleValidation(ruleData, "LO");
```

Web Service generated code:

```
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://www.example.org/LathamInt/RuleValidation", 
    RequestNamespace="http://www.example.org/LathamInt/", 
    ResponseNamespace="http://www.example.org/LathamInt/", 
    Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, 
    ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
[return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute("ruleValidationResp", 
    Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
[return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("rule", 
    Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, 
    IsNullable=false)]
public RuleValidationResponseRule[] RuleValidation([System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)] 
    RuleValidationRuleData ruleData, 
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()] string company) {
    object[] results = this.Invoke("RuleValidation", new object[] {
                ruleData,
                company});
    return ((RuleValidationResponseRule[])(results[0]));
}
```

XML passed to the webservice (from Fiddler):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <RuleValidation company="LO" xmlns="http://www.example.org/LathamInt/">
            <ruleData xmlns="">
                <rule ruleID="GDSP" />
                <varData varName="GuideSpace" varValue="3" />
            </ruleData>
        </RuleValidation>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

XML returned from the service (from Fiddler):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:lat="http://www.example.org/LathamInt/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <RuleValidationResponse>
            <ruleValidationResp>
                <rule result="0" ruleId="GDSP" status="success">
                    <expression pre="@GuideSpace > 3" post="3 > 3"/>
                </rule>
            </ruleValidationResp>
        </RuleValidationResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Response definition in C# generated code:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.17929")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://www.example.org/LathamInt/")]
public partial class RuleValidationResponseRule {

    private RuleValidationResponseRuleExpression expressionField;

    private string resultField;

    private string ruleIdField;

    private string statusField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public RuleValidationResponseRuleExpression expression {
        get {
            return this.expressionField;
        }
        set {
            this.expressionField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string result {
        get {
            return this.resultField;
        }
        set {
            this.resultField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string ruleId {
        get {
            return this.ruleIdField;
        }
        set {
            this.ruleIdField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string status {
        get {
            return this.statusField;
        }
        set {
            this.statusField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a lot of code.  Perhaps you can help us out a little by breakpointing the code, stepping through it, and telling us where the data disappears into null.  We won't be able to set a machine up to check this out, so you're in a much better position to troubleshoot.

Comment: I agree, however, Visual Studio doesn't seem to break inside the generated web service code.  So I'm stuck trying to understand the generated code to see if a namespace is out of place or something like that.

Comment: Then put in some logging statements.

Comment: This line here: object[] results = this.Invoke("RuleValidation", new object[] { ruleData, company}); shows that results has 1 element, and that element is null.

Comment: I don't quite understand that line of code... Is it invoking *itself*?

Comment: This is code that is auto-generated by .Net when you add a web service.  The FQDN of Invoke is System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.  This is the call that actually does magic to call the web service and map the results back to the object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do believe I've solved it.

In the return XML, this line

```
<RuleValidationResponse>
```

means the return tag does not have a namespace.  It needs to be changed to

```
<lat:RuleValidationResponse>
```

Either that, or modify the line

```
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute ("http://www.example.org/LathamInt/RuleValidation", 
    RequestNamespace="http://www.example.org/LathamInt/", 
    ResponseNamespace="http://www.example.org/LathamInt/",  //<-- ** Change this line
    Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, 
    ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
```

to

```
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute ("http://www.example.org/LathamInt/RuleValidation", 
    RequestNamespace="http://www.example.org/LathamInt/", 
    ResponseNamespace="",  //<-- ** Change this line
    Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, 
    ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
```

Comment: 1. Replace [][] with [] in Reference.cs - checked 
2. Use Web Reference instead of Service reference - checked
3. Spent half a day searching workarounds - checked 
4. Read 10+ articles mentioning Axis / Java and .NET integration - checked
5. Found this response and a working solution - checked
:) Thanks!